# Running vcvars32.bat before compiling in Code::Blocks?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, environment-variables, codeblocks

I've installed Visual Studio C++ Express 2012 and want to use it's compiler with Code::Blocks. Starting `cl.exe` does not work (missing *mspdb100.dll*) until I run `vcvars32.bat`, but that does only hold on for the current session in the Command-line. The same applies to compiling with Code::Blocks.

**How can I make it run the `vcvars32.bat` before compiling?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *Workaround*

That workaround is actually not what I was looking for, but it works, and that is important. Instead of letting *Code::Blocks* running `cl.exe` directly, I've set-up a simple batch-script that runs `vcvars32.bat` before running the actual compiler.

```
REM File: cl.bat
call vcvars32.bat
call cl.exe %1 %*
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties, you have a section `Build events`. You can add `vcvars32.bat` to the pre-build event.

[image: Pre-build event]

Comment: Is there a possibility to add this to the general compiler-settings?

Comment: @NiklasR you can copy configurations or have the same setting for multiple configurations, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Why does your CB gui look so nice? :O   2) Hm, I mean, I want to it run generally when compiling with VC, I don't want to add this to each project I'm going to compile with VC ...

Comment: @NiklasR 1)it's VS2010 Professional. 2)I don't believe you can.

Comment: Ahh! Anyway, just tested adding the `vcvars32.bat` to that list (in CB of course), but that did not fix the problem. In the CB console, I can see the output of that batch, but it doesn't affect.

Answer (score 0):

To run the .bat before compiling in Code Blocks(16.01), go to the project build options and its under the "pre/post build steps" tab. This tab only appears in the project settings, not the compiler settings.

However, adding "vcvars32.bat" (or "vcvars64.bat") to the pre build steps didn't fix the error for me.

I found the directory where the library is and added it to the linker search directories. This gave errors about further missing libraries. I added the following paths to my linker settings. These will almost certainly be different for you. I'm installed MSVS 2017 community edition. For some reason known only to Microsoft, the necessary libraries are installed on two different drives.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\lib\x64
D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\um\x64
D:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.16299.0\ucrt\x64

Note that the .bat script is no longer necessary if you add these paths by hand.